# Set deployer address in Hardhat tests

Tags: testing, hardhat, unittesting, hardhat-deploy

I am using HardHat to write some unit tests. This part is related to deploying the contract, though I am not seeing how hardhat set address of deployer here.

Say we have these addresses:

```js
let user1: SignerWithAddress;
let user2: SignerWithAddress;
let user3: SignerWithAddress;

[user1, user2, user3] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

now `user2` needs to deploy a contract using `getContractFactory`:

```js
const SomeContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("SomeContract");
const contract = await SomeContract.deploy();
```

I am not seeing any parameter for setting the deployer of this contract. How can I specify `user2` as the deployer here?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do this by overriding signer in `ethers.getContractFactory`. In the following code the deployer of contract will be `user2`:

```js
const [user1, user2] = await ethers.getSigners();
const SomeContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("SomeContract", {
  signer: user2,
});

const contract = await SomeContract.deploy();
```